# Unable to install mysqlclient on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, python, mysql, pip

I want to install MySQL on my Ubuntu 20.10 desktop, but I'm facing issues.
I tried installing `python3-dev` and `libmysqlclient-dev`.

When running:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

I keep getting the error below:

[image: pip3 install mysqlclient error]

How may I solve this?

Comment: @BeastofCarerbannog I did install libffi-dev and executed ldconfig. Still getting the same error. While doing pip install mysqlclient. The error is still the same.

Answer (score 19):

Check this thread, maybe it helps you.

[Error installing libmysqlclient-dev on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243444/error-installing-libmysqlclient-dev-on-ubuntu-20-04/1331891#1331891)

Step 0: `sudo apt install python3-dev build-essential`

Step 1: `sudo apt install libssl1.1`

Step 2: `sudo apt install libssl1.1=1.1.1f-1ubuntu2`

Step 3: `sudo apt install libssl-dev`

Step 4: `sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev`

Step 5: `pip3 install mysqlclient`

That's it!

*ps: To find out these all steps, I was spent almost 4-5 Hours. :D*

Comment: I have venv set to Python 3.9. In my case, I use `sudo apt install python3.9-dev`. Anything else is the same. and it works!

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) you should do:

- `sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential`
  Debian / Ubuntu
- `sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel`
  Red Hat / CentOS

After that just do `pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: It works for Ubuntu 18.04 too.

Comment: Thank you so much. It also works on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It was giving me troubles everytime I try to install mysqlclient.

Answer (score 2):

This can usually be resolved with the `libffi-dev` libraries; `libffi.so` specifically. It can be installed via `apt` with:

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
```

***Note:** I have not found a way to install this via* `pip3`. *Do let me know if you find it somewhere.*

Once `libffi-dev` is installed, run `ldconfig` to load the new `.so`.

***Important:** If you compiled your own Python installation, then you will need to recompile it for* `libffi-dev` *to be loaded.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble while setting up virtual environment then do mention python version:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev

sudo apt-get install mysql-client 

sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev 

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

### Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name. Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually

If you encounter something like above message in between too then, below command will do the thing which is setting above os environment variables.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential pkg-config

pip install mysqlclient
```

References - https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient#readme