# Unable to install mysqlclient on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: 22.04, python, mysql, pip

I want to install MySQL on my Ubuntu 22.04.3 for a Django course I'm taking. I used the following command:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I tried the suggestions in this thread: [Unable to install mysqlclient on Ubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321141/unable-to-install-mysqlclient-on-ubuntu-20-10)

I followed the steps mentioned but didn't resolve it.

Step 1 wasn't working because `libssl1.1` is deprecated so I installed `libssl3`.

Step 2 does not work even if I use:

```
sudo apt install libssl3=1.1.1f-1ubuntu2
```

instead of:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.1=1.1.1f-1ubuntu2
```

I guess is not the right way.

Then I successfully installed the following:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

But even after this I keep getting error when running `pip install mysqlclient`:

[image]

Will appreciate some help or guidance to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found` is telling you, that `pkg-config` is missing.

To install `pkg-config` package, run this command:

```
sudo apt install pkg-config
```

Comment: This resolved it! I installed this package and was able to install mysqlclient afterwards. Really appreciated.