# Unable to install MySQL client via pip3 or pip

Tags: python, mysql, pip

I get the exact same error as shown in
[Unable to install mysqlclient on Ubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321141/unable-to-install-mysqlclient-on-ubuntu-20-10) and
[Error installing libmysqlclient-dev on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243444/error-installing-libmysqlclient-dev-on-ubuntu-20-04/1331891#1331891). But after doing all these, if I install mysqlclient via,
"sudo pip3 install mysqlclient" it installs successfully. The problem is I don't need it in root since I'm using virtual env and my django is not in root, that is, python in venv does not detect mysqlclient in root.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found a solution, apparently conda's venv was messing up with my project's venv, so I disabled it using "conda deactivate" and then installed and it was successful.
So follow the links pasted above and make sure you're not in any other environment other than your own.